# How to get header row data related to left column name (whose data are not empty)

Tags: excel, vba

Good day to all! My sample data looks like below screenshot. So, when I will select `Harun` in `J2` cell then my expected result is `xxx, zzz, ppp`. My logic to get result as Harun has value in `xxx` and `zzz` and `ppp` column. With the following array formula I can do that but it is not dynamic. Row (array for index function) is hard-coded here. So, can we make it dynamic so that I can get the all header item when I select any name in `J2` cell? Appreciate your help.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$G$2,,SMALL(IF($C$3:$G$3<>"",COLUMN($C$3:$G$3),""),ROWS($B$3:$B3))-2)
```

***Sample Data Screenshot***
[image]

**Only excel formula is preferable. If not possible then we can go with VBA.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In J3 Cell**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$G$2,,SMALL(IF(OFFSET($B$2,MATCH(J$2,$B$3:$B$8,0),1,,5)<>"",COLUMN(OFFSET($B$2,MATCH(J$2,$B$3:$B$8,0),1,,5))-2,""),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Drag the formula down and right

Comment: You formula works for me. Is it anyway possible to solve it without array formula so that I can use it in named range.

Comment: There is no { } symbol in the formula proposed. Thus, this is NOT an array formula. It is a normal one (individual, cell independent formula). Just change the all reference to J2 (maintaining the $ sign location) will do.