# Reverse index match with multiple outputs

Tags: excel

Given a matrix like the one shown below, I would like to be able to input a person's name and output every group the person is in.

[image: Example matrix]

I am OK with the reverse index match lookup but do not know how to amend the formula to produce an array that works. I have tried using SMALL/LARGE function but can't get it to work.

My formula for CELL C15 is

```
=INDEX($C$2:$I$2,,MATCH("ü",INDEX($C$3:$I$12,MATCH($B$15,$B$3:$B$12$,0),),0))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the post. I think it same as your question. [How to get header row data related to left column name (whose data are not empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545844/how-to-get-header-row-data-related-to-left-column-name-whose-data-are-not-empty)

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula in your C15 and pull down until you need (close with ctrl+shift+enter)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$I$2,SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH($B$15,B:B,0)&":I"&MATCH($B$15,B:B,0))<>"x",TRANSPOSE(ROW($1:$7)),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

If you need to get the reverse result (list of people by group). Do the same with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$12,SMALL(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,MATCH($B$15,$2:$2,0))&":"&ADDRESS(12,MATCH(B$15,$2:$2,0)))="v",ROW($1:$10),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. How would you adjust the INDIRECT so that it worked in reverse, i.e Given a group, output the individuals?

Comment: I updated my answer with a formula you could use to get the list of persons by inputing the group (assuming the same cells)